# Global Hotkey does not work in Fullscreen game

Tags: c#, screenshot, global-hotkey

I am creating a program for taking screenshots of a game, out of the game. When I press the hotkey it works, but with the open game in fullscreen it does not detect the key.

My code:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;

    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_HOTKEY:
        {
            if ((short)m.WParam == 1)
            {
                start = DateTime.Now;
                progressBar1.Maximum = 1;
                progressBar1.Step = 1;
                progressBar1.Value = 0;

                DoRequest();
            }
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I register the global key using:

```
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 1, (int)KeyModifier.None, Keys.F11);
```

Help-me :/

**SOLVED!**
Resolved, I managed to fix through this project:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with most games (not all of them) is that they use DirectInput (DirectX) and not windows message pump to read keystrokes. I have also written an application using voice recognition that sends keys to games and experienced the same issue which I solved by looking at DirectX keycodes. [ref: DirectInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee418273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How can I implement this in my code? I do not get it right, i tried to put the F11 key of DirectX and did not work.

Comment: Please see if the following link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb153252(v=vs.85).aspx can assist you.

Comment: Thanks, I managed through this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but I solved it by running my program with Admin privileges.

Comment: Awesome, but still actual :) Thanks

Comment: This actually fixed the problem for me!! Thanks... I made a global hook keys app but didnt work while my game is running until I saw your answer and realized that my game is running as admin while the app is not. Thanks such a life saver